# Typescript - index signature intersection issue

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0, typescript1.8

I have the following type:

```
type MyType = {
    ['x']?: string;
    ['y']?: number;
} & { [key: string]: string };
```

When I write this:

```
const a: MyType = {
    'x': 'str',
    'y': 5
}
```

I get an error (y is a number while expecting a string) which makes sense according to the index signature.
But when I write this:

```
const b: MyType = {};
b['x'] = 'str2';
b['y'] = 6
```

It works fine.
What is the difference between the two? Should this even work?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59896317/typescript-key-index-signature-only-for-all-properties-that-are-not-defined); the question here isn't exactly a duplicate, but the answer is related.  [microsoft/TypeScript#17867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867) might be the canonical issue about this, although there's no great answer in there from anyone who can definitively say if it "should" work to read/write properties whose type conflicts in the two intersection members.  [ms/TS#37809](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37809) is also related.

Comment: I feel like this is an issue with the ts compiler.
I know that MyType shouldn't be written that way, This question is more about the ts compiler.
For var a - it behaves like the index signature applies to everything - and you get a contradiction - and therefor an error.  
For var b - it behaves like the index signature applies to everything other than the x param and y param. so ts is ok with it and you don't get an error.
(error for ts compiler)

Sounds like a ts compiler bug - or I'm missing something.

Comment: Did you look at ms/TS#37809 linked above?

Comment: Oh Yeah, I missed that link
Yeah, Thanks for the help - it is just a built in inconsistent behavior with ts